# How to use SplashScreen with null safety?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

There came an error that splashScreen doesn't support null safety. It got fixed when I downgraded the SDK version but my question is, how can I use SplashScreen with null safety without downgrading. If I can't then what are the alternatives to SplashScreen which does the same task as SplashScreen but support null safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**flutter_native_splash** is flutters favorite splash screen package, it supports null safety as well. You can use that https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash